# How to share python instance to c++?

Tags: python, c++

I'm using python for my c++ program's sub script language.
I bind my c++ class to python to use it in python side.

This system must can share(pass) c++ instance to python.
And even Python (script side) can create new instance also it must be share by c++ side too.

But python(or..java, c#)'s class type is reference type.

```
#MyClass class has class type member test 
data1 = MyClass()
data2 = MyClass()

#so data1's test will point data2.test object
data1.test = data2.test
```

So it will be work like a c++'s pointer.

But in c++, class is not reference type. 
So assignment operation will call `= operator.`
if =operator will not overloaded then it will work value copy.

```
ClassInstance1 = ClassInstance2
```

Well If you create some objects in python, and share (pass) to c++ side.
like...

```
 Character* pChara = PythonSideObjectToCpp("data1");
```

The data work rule is different between c++ and python.
So i think c++ can not 1:1 match with pythonlike above code.
It will need more interface about get, set or control python's reference type member.

How do you think about this?
I don't think that python instance can extract to c++ purely. 
Well... but it can extract python instance's clone object.

Comment: How do you connect Python and C++? Do you use the CPython API? Consider using [Boost Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html) instead, where you can relatively easily pass a C++ object to the Python code as a Python object.

Comment: I use c / python api. well.. boost::python's extract<T>() return python object's copy.  not the instance original. So i can not set value to that.